# How do I extend the Func delegate to contain more than the maximum four parameters?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, delegates, lambda

I have been using LINQ with compiled queries, basically passing into the compiled query using `Func` but the problem is that it has a maximum of four parameters.

Is it good practice to extend this?

Is there any way to extend this or should I create my own delegate?

Sometimes I need to pass six params and others five and others four or less... so with four or less I could continue using the `Func` delegate.

Currently passing in data context and a mix of the params I need are dependent on each individual compiled query.

Comment: @Mitch: Can you help me with mine (Anything over 50 isnt the end of the world in my book) :D

Comment: I agree with Ruben - it would be wiser to introduce a new class to carry all these parameters around (you might even want to use an interface to give you looser coupling). In other words, you would end with something like `Func<IMyData>`, where `IMyData` contains a bunch of (readonly) properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare your own delegates - it's only a single line of code to do so. See [my examples for declaring the .NET 3.5 delegates in .NET 2.0](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) for a sort of template, if you need it.

I don't know how well this will work with LINQ compiled queries - hopefully it won't be a problem, but your use case isn't quite clear enough to me to say for sure.

Note that in [.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system(VS.100).aspx) there's support for Func/Action with up to 8 parameters.

Comment: Thanks jon, so i presume if .net 4.0 is going to have up to 8 params its not a good idea to create my own Func with 5 params.. i should name it something else OR AT LEAST put it in its own namespace?

Comment: @mark: It depends on what you're building, and how you're planning to approach .NET 4.0. If it's a library which should work with different versions of .NET, that's tricky. If it's an application which you can "upgrade" once by removing your delegate declarations, that's simpler.

Comment: Thanks Jon, thats what i will do it just remove the delegate when .net 4.0 comes along

Comment: Jon, i have 1 question - maybe you can confirm, the new delegate is working but i need to pass it into CompileQuery of LINQ .. and that only supports up to 4 as well... I have looked at the code with reflector but it seems maybe the best way would be to pass the parameters in a parameter Object as per Ruben's suggestion.. But this means i going to have to create a new parameter object for every different collection of parameters?  Do you know of a better way?

Comment: Not really - if you need to pass it into LINQ to SQL, you're going to have to use a delegate type that LINQ to SQL understands.

Comment: Agreed, so i am going to create a parameter class and pass it into the stanadard FUNC and then into CompiledQuery ...  Thank you for conifrming this!! - i learn something new every day!!!

Answer (score 2):

What Jon said plus...

As you've suggested, generally you shouldnt end up with too many params - generally you should find some uniting concept jumping out telling you to [Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/sean_chambers/archive/2009/08/23/refactoring-day-23-introduce-parameter-object.aspx). Having said that, 4 wouldnt be the place where I'd place a 'that's just crazy' line.

Comment: Thanks Ruben for your comment, i will keep this for the future! Currently i need only a max of 6 i think - so i think its quite manageable

Comment: Hi Ruben, i am thinking of using your technique but in the example it creates a parameter object with types i.e. int,string etc etc.. Do you know if its possible to use a kind of generic version so that i can use this object for passing all different types inside. I could just specify it as Object i suppose but then i will need to Cast to the actual type?

Comment: Hi Mark, The reference to the example of the pattern was inserted by an editor (Thanks Groo!). If you're looking to use a predefined class, that's more like Tuples (which are in F# and .NET 4). The main point of IPO is that that you'd create a new class with a good name which represents the overall concept behind the set of partams you're passing, e.g., instead of "header, body, trailer" you have a `DocumentDefinition` with properties or methods wrapping it up. There's nothing stopping you using a Dictionary as a Bag to pass them as, but that would be a differnt approach.

Comment: For info on tuples (Like Twitter, SO counts the letters of a URL as real letters!), see http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2009/07/07/building-tuple-matt-ellis.aspx

Comment: Just reading your conversation w/ The Horse... This may or may not be applicable to your context - its just a general refactoring that applies when you're find yourself passing lots of parameters that are a class waiting to be identified.

Comment: thanks, i have managed to get something going...thanks for your comments